# xymatrix/commutative diagrams

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a commutative diagram?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram)

Today i wanted to include a drawing of a commutative diagram in my answer on math.stackexchange.com - but did not find any way of doing that.

Isn't there yet such a thing to render 
$$\xymatrix{\ar @{} [dr] |{\#} P \ar[r]^f \ar[d]_\pi & P \ar[d]^\pi \\ M \ar[r]_{\bar f} & M }$$
or is it that i used the wrong syntax.
If it is not included i would make this a feature request.

Comment: `xy` and similar packages aren't implemented in MathJaX, yet. See [here](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/tex.html) for the list of available commands and see also [this discussion](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/104/mathjax/) on meta.MO.

Comment: Another [related thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/is-beginpicture-endpicture-not-allowed)

Comment: shall i delete it as it really is a duplicate?

Comment: As you wish. I would probably leave it to document that it *is* requested from time to time. Nothing worse can happen than that the thread is closed as a duplicate. By the way: when I need a diagram, I sometimes create it in a LaTeX document on my computer and upload a screen shot.

Comment: ah good idea to draw and screenshot it - will do that from now on if i've got time.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Deleting the question would make it impossible for you to receive further helpful comments such as those above (and this), cf. [my post here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3338/242).